# Innerjoin in Linq-to-sql for this in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I use asp.net mvc... How to write an inner join in linq-to-sql for this sql query

```
select M.Mat_id,M.Mat_Name,T.Name as Measurement,M.Mat_Type as Description 
 from Material as M inner join MeasurementTypes as T 
  on M.MeasurementTypeId = T.Id where M.Is_Deleted=0
```

And my repository class has this,

```
    public class ConstructionRepository
    {
        private CRDataContext db = new CRDataContext();
        public IQueryable<Material> FindAllMaterials()
        {
            return db.Materials;
        }
    }
```

My result `db.Materials` is the table data.. I dont want that i want to innerjoin with another table and show the data....

```
public class ConstructionRepository
 {
    private CRDataContext db = new CRDataContext();
     public IQueryable<Material> FindAllMaterials()
    {
                //inner join query
     }
    }
```

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return anonymous types with the details you've specified in your SQL query but you may prefer to simply return the material objects themselves.

```
from material in db.Materials
from measurementType in material.MeasurementTypes
where material.Is_Deleted = false
select new {
    material..Mat_id,
    material.Mat_Name,
    Measurement = measurementType.Name,
    Description = material.Mat_Type
}
```

Comment: @Daniel ya it does return anonymous types.... Ok i ll try ur answer and let you know...